# Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined

Tags: c++, gdb

I wrote a function similar to this:

```
class abc {
    private :
    int m_var ;
    public :
    int func() { return m_var ; }
};
```

When I try to print the `func()` using an `abc` object pointer in `gdb`, it is giving the error:

`**Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined**`

How to can I print values from an inlined function?

Comment: Try this to avoid inline function.

[how-can-i-tell-gcc-not-to-inline-a-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474030/how-can-i-tell-gcc-not-to-inline-a-function)

Comment: ^ Possible duplicate of [How can I tell gcc not to inline a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474030/how-can-i-tell-gcc-not-to-inline-a-function?lq=1)

Comment: For template function see [C++, STL, GDB: Cannot evaluate function maybe inlined - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633787/c-stl-gdb-cannot-evaluate-function-maybe-inlined) (summary: requires explicit template instantiation)

Comment: See also [c++ - Possible to call inline functions in gdb and/or emit them using GCC? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029834/possible-to-call-inline-functions-in-gdb-and-or-emit-them-using-gcc)

Answer (score 24):

You got this error because you put func's definition in the class body and it's small enough, so, first, the compiler inlined this function ---- that means, the compile will substitute all the appearance of this function's call with its definition, and no definition of this function will be in the executable file. And, second, you didn't really call that function in your program, so in fact, this function never exist in your final executable file!

To solve that:

1. You can put the definition of func outside the class body.
2. Call func in your program anywhere.

Answer (score 18):

When the function is inlined, it doesn't appear as a proper symbol in the executable, so there's no way for gdb to execute it. The simplest thing to do is probably to compile with function inlining disabled, either by `-fno-inline-functions` or (still better) `-O0`.

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can disable it on specific functions with `__attribute((noinline))__`. There is also `-fno-inline-small-functions`, IIRC. Also, function inlining will not be enabled with `-O1` either, if you still want some optimization.

Comment: In this case, adding -fno-inline-functions doesn't solve the problem. TRY IT with your compiler first and then post your answer.

Comment: @nicky_zs, it is working for me with -O0 or -fno-inline-functions.

Comment: @bytbox, really? Did you call the function func in your code? I tried this: if I didn't call this function in my code, -fno-inline-functions  doesn't work.

Comment: Ah no, I assumed it would actually be called elsewhere.

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and the problem wasn't inlining, as @nicky_zs pointed out, the function was being removed by the linker because it wasn't directly called.

Comment: To prevent the linker from removing an uncalled function, add `__attribute__((used))`.

Comment: Unfortunately even these methods doesn't work when the data type is function-local (internal linkage).