# gdb stl functions still show as inlined after disabling optimizations

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I have built gdb-7.12 with python support and have enabled pretty printing and configured my gdbinit file by following https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport.

But whenever i print the size of any container:

```
p ivec.size()
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

Here is the MCVE i am using

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<int> ivec;
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried different compiling options

```
g++-6 -g -O0 -fno-inline-functions -gdwarf-2 Source.cpp --std=c++14
```

In fact i have tried every combination of the above options, and always the same problem.

I tried switching to gdb-7.11 (also built from source) to see if it fixes the problem and also switched to g++-4.8, none of them seem to fix the issue.

What am i doing wrong? Is there some specific order in which you have to give the options?

**EDIT:**
Many people have suggested some macros to solve the problem, but my problem isn't to somehow print these functions, i can write my own pretty print methods for that.

My question is why are the functions showing up as inlined even after Disabling optimizations with **-O0** options?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163730/cannot-evaluate-function-may-be-inlined ?

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-standard-container-stdmap-contents-with-gdb

Comment: @UKMonkey I don't think it is, i have seen those question and i tried out the optimization options and i don't require pretty printing to print the size of a vector

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cannot evaluate function -- may be in-lined" error in GDB for STL template container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633787/cannot-evaluate-function-may-be-in-lined-error-in-gdb-for-stl-template-cont) (okay I guarantee *this* duplicate target is correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is why are the functions showing up as inlined even after Disabling optimizations with -O0 options?

g++ will only instantiate templates that are actually used by your program, and your program doesn't actually use the `size` method.

You can check this using `nm`:

```
$ nm -C q|grep size
$
```

If I change your program to use `return ivec.size()`, then I can:

```
(gdb) p ivec.size()
$1 = 0
```

This whole situation with inlining and non-instantiation is why the gdb `xmethod` support was written.  And, libstdc++ has some xmethods (though I didn't check if it specifically has this one).  I recommend using that.

Answer (score 3):

The GDB error message `Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined` is a bit misleading as inlining isn't the only reason for a function being unavailable.

In your example, `std::vector<T>::size()` simple isn't instantiated (into `std::vector<int>::size()`) at compile time because it isn't used.

It depends on the version of your GDB pretty printing support if it can work around the missing `size()` instantiation when you type `p ivec.size()` or `call ivec.size()` (e.g. GDB 8.0.1 on Fedora 27 can). But even with older versions of the STL pretty printing support you can work around this issue by just printing the vector itself, i.e.:

```
(gdb) p ivec
$1 = std::vector of length 0, capacity 0
```

However, you can explicitly make sure that `size()` is instantiated either by using it somewhere in your program or by explicitly instantiating the complete template class for `int` in one translation unit:

```
template class std::vector<int>;
```