# evaluating methods of libc++ in gdb when using clang

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clang, inline

When compiling this

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo;
    foo.push_back( 1 );
    printf( "%zu\n", foo.size() );
}
```

with `clang++ foo.cpp -stdlib=libc++ -g`, when running a.out in gdb and trying to show the result of `foo.size()`, gdb says "Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined".

Is there a way to avoid the compiler's inlining in debug mode? I could use libstdc++, but it is quite painful when it is needed to go inside the templates (many many subcalls plus indentation is sometimes space-based and sometimes tab-based).

I am running with Debian 9 (stretch) using libc++-dev v3.5 with clang 3.8 (tried with clang 5.0 too, same result) and gdb 7.12.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/22163730/817643

Comment: I must admit I didn't noticed this one, but here there is at least 2 differences: it works with libstdc++, and the inlining is not under my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libstdc++ implements so called Python xmethods, see [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Xmethods-In-Python.html):

> Xmethods are additional methods or replacements for existing methods
>   of a C++ class. This feature is useful for those cases where a method
>   defined in C++ source code could be inlined or optimized out by the
>   compiler, making it unavailable to GDB. For such cases, one can define
>   an xmethod to serve as a replacement for the method defined in the C++
>   source code. GDB will then invoke the xmethod, instead of the C++
>   method, to evaluate expressions. One can also use xmethods when
>   debugging with core files. Moreover, when debugging live programs,
>   invoking an xmethod need not involve running the inferior (which can
>   potentially perturb its state). Hence, even if the C++ method is
>   available, it is better to use its replacement xmethod if one is
>   defined.

That's why you can call mock `foo.size()` even if the real `foo.size()` was inlined by compiler when using libstdc++. As far as I know there is no alike xmethod implementation for libc++.