# C++, GDB: Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging a program with gdb: `gdb --args ...`
I added a breakpoint to check the new variables(vectors) that have the right dimensions,
`p myvector.size()`, works ok but when I try to do:

`p myvector.at(i)`  to check the values(which would be helpful)  gdb answers:

> Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined

Does anyone have any hint or idea?

Comment: gdb is able to call a function in the running process, but not if the linker discards this function or if it is inlined. This often occurs with access methods such as `operator[]` and `.at`. Just printing the vector should use the pretty-printer, which is enough for small vectors. You can also directly access the internal variables in vector to get the pointer storing the elements and print from there. For instance, with a vector `v` you could try `v._M_impl._M_start[i]`. Knowing this is also useful when you are debugging from a core file, without a process running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++, STL, GDB: Cannot evaluate function maybe inlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633787/c-stl-gdb-cannot-evaluate-function-maybe-inlined)

Comment: (tl;dr: Explicitly instantiate the class. `template class std::vector<int>`.